# Input Error. Still uses old input even after taking new input

Tags: java, input

I have to make the code such that the user cannot enter a wrong value.

```
    public static String getFraction() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fraction = s.next();
        if (validFraction(fraction)){
            return fraction;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("Invalid fraction. Please enter a 
            fraction (a/b) or integer (a), where a and b are 
            integers and b is not zero : ");
            getFraction();
        }
```

Here when the user enters a wrong value it prompts the user to put a new value but it still takes the old value.

```
        return null;
    }
```

For example, say if I input a/b it prompts me to input again but since I use a parseInt method later in the code it shows me an error like :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For 
input string: "a"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Num 
berFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at FractionCalculator.numerator(FractionCalculator.java:105)
    at FractionCalculator.main(FractionCalculator.java:15)
```

Valid Fraction function :

```
public static boolean validFraction(String f) {
    if (f.contains("/")) {
        int n = f.indexOf("/");
        String num = f.substring(0, n);
        String den = f.substring(n+1);
        for (int i = 1; i<n; i++) {
            char a = num.charAt(i);
            char b = den.charAt(i);
            if (a == '-' || b == '-') {
                return false;
            }
        }
        f.replaceAll("[-]", "");
        if (isNumber(num, den)) {
            if (den.equals("0"))
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (f.matches("^[0-9]+$"))
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you perhaps show the code of `validFraction`? The problem is not apparent in the code you've posted.

Comment: Please share the code of validFraction method...

Comment: A first hint: if you call `getFraction` recursively, you should return the returned value. Otherwise, the first callee of `getFraction` will always retrieve `null` iff the user has to enter it's input a second time

Answer (score 0):

The exception seems to be coming from a place where Strings (a, b) are getting parsed as Integers.

If you intend to actually do so and check if the string is numeric or not, then it's advisable to catch NumberFormatException and return the status accordingly as follows:

```
      private static boolean isNumber(String string)
      {
        try
        {
          Integer.parseInt(string);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
```